# Connecting two planes together successfully

Tags: modeling, vertices

My question is how do I connect two vertices together to make two planes one object? I used tiny cad to do the intersections but they didn't really connect
[image: object imported from tiny cad, in blender]

[image]

Comment: It isn't very clear what your question is about. Your image have no notation and description to what you are trying to achieve. Can you elaborate and highlight which part of the mesh are you trying to modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After removing doubles (select all > <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*) and recalculating normals (select all > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) only this part of geometry is displayed as non-manifold:

[image: T-Mesh preview]

When inspecting one of those sides it becomes clear that vertices of thin part of mesh aren't connected to thick part:

[image: t-mesh problem]

You should connect those vertices to edge located between thick and thin parts.

1. Select top and bottom vertices of that edge. Subdivide them with <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide*, in Last Operator panel (<kbd>F6</kbd>) choose 2 subdiviosions.

   [image: selecting and subdividing]
2. Select top subdivided vertex, select top original vertex and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> > *At Last* to merge them.

   [image: merging vertices]
3. Repeat that for 3 other vertices (to do that faster you can use Repeat Last operator. Once you merged first pair of vertices select next pair appropriately and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. It will repeat last action).

*Optionally: you could edit topology a bit to avoid Ngons on thick part of this mesh. However this shouldn't be important if you aren't going to add Subsurf on the model.*

Answer (score 2):

You don't need [mesh_tinyCAD](https://github.com/zeffii/mesh_tinyCAD) for this.

Delete the edges that touch the other edges,

[image]

then select any remaining edge and press F. to fill.

[image]

Comment: Even as I do this it still shows as an incomplete mesh. I tried merging the two vertices I made using tinycad but they are not merging

Comment: I wrote the tinyCAD addon - and fail to see how it could be useful here, when Blender's built in tools are perfectly fine for it. Don't give up :)

Comment: I see. I guess my question was how to fix a vertex that wouldn't let 2 lines connect. Thnkd for the help!